How to filter for multiple senders where each has a wildcard in gmail?
I have two sender domains: A and X.A ...so e.g. bla@A.com and pee@X.A.com
What I am trying is to create a filter which catches all mails from both domains with wildcards before the @-sign.

from:(*@A.com) works
from:(*@X.A.com) works

but

from:(*@A.com) OR from:(*@X.A.com) does not work

I played around with the parantheses, but that did not work for me either.
How to make this work?

The filter in your question works fine for me as-is, what are you seeing? You could try using from:(@A.com OR @X.A.com) instead, or with brackets to make a list like {from:@A.com from:@X.A.com}. Gmail filters ignore asterisks - you can see the full list of filter operators here: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190.
